# Retrieving userid/phone number in Twilio whatsapp/SMS API

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am building a whatsapp chatbot in my Twilio sandbox. I have gone through the API but I cannot figure out how to retrieve a person's phone number (the sender's phone number), assuming this is even possible? The reason being I want to limit the number of actions each user can do in a given time period.

Not sure if this is helpful but is the information I get on ngrok when I sent a request

```
POST /bot HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

X-Twilio-Signature: XXXX

I-Twilio-Idempotency-Token: XXXX

Accept: */*

Content-Length: 318

Host: XXXX

Cache-Control: max-age=259200

User-Agent: TwilioProxy/1.1

connection: close

X-Forwarded-Proto: https

X-Forwarded-For: XXXX


SmsMessageSid=SMcaXXXXXX&NumMedia=0&SmsSid=SMcaXXXXX&SmsStatus=received&Body=Help&To=whatsapp%3A%2XXXX&NumSegments=1&MessageSid=XXXXX&AccountSid=XXXX&From=whatsapp%3A%2BXXXXXX&ApiVersion=2010-04-01
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by first requesting the ngrok HTTP that sends the whatsapp messages and then extracting the number since the number.

```
number = request.values.get('From', '')
#removed non numerical 
cleaned_number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', number)
```